# ActionScript 3 Mouse Move event not dispatching

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

Script problem is that every movieclip dispatch down and up mouse event but mouse move event is not dispatching by some movieclips, which is an unexpected behaviour while I have traced the down event and it trace successfully on every object

also recommend your feedback on my code, thanks.

```
    private function loadPurchasedClip(){
            var decorationItem:String;
            var lastItemIndex:uint = this.getChildIndex(tree1);
            var item:Sprite;

            for(var a in purchasedItems){

                for(var b in purchasedItems[a]){

                if(purchasedItems[a][b].item=='shed'){
                    item = new shed();
                } else {

                    var ClassDefinition:Class = loadedDecorationItem.purchaseItem(purchasedItems[a][b].item) as Class;


                    item = new ClassDefinition();

                }
                item.x = purchasedItems[a][b].posX;
                item.y = purchasedItems[a][b].posY;


                item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function(e:MouseEvent){
                        Mouse.cursor = "hand";
                        e.target.startDrag(false);

                        dusbin.visible = true;
                    item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,trashMe);
                });

                item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function(e:MouseEvent){

                    Mouse.cursor = "auto";
                    e.target.stopDrag();
                    externalPhpCall(e);
                    dusbin.visible = false;
                    if(trashClip){
                        removeChild(trashClip);
                        trashClip = null;
                    }
                });
                item.mouseChildren = false;


                // if item is fence or flowers then move them behind the tree
                if(
                    String(purchasedItems[a][b].item).indexOf('fence')!=-1
                    ||
                    String(purchasedItems[a][b].item).indexOf('flower')!=-1
                ){
                    addChildAt(item,lastItemIndex);

                    lastItemIndex++;
                } else {
                    addChildAt(item,this.numChildren-2);
                }

                purchasedNameAr[getChildIndex(item)] = purchasedItems[a][b].item;

            }

        }
```

Comment: you have your mouse Event inside the mouseMove function?

Comment: try using e.target not item when you register the mouse move event.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz 'Severiaan' Grela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        private  function loadPurchasedClip(){
        var decorationItem:String;
        var lastItemIndex:uint = this.getChildIndex(tree1);
        var item:Sprite;
        var Move:Boolean

        for(var a in purchasedItems){

            for(var b in purchasedItems[a]){

            if(purchasedItems[a][b].item=='shed'){
                item = new shed();
            } else {

                var ClassDefinition:Class = loadedDecorationItem.purchaseItem(purchasedItems[a][b].item) as Class;

                item = new ClassDefinition();

            }
            item.x = purchasedItems[a][b].posX;
            item.y = purchasedItems[a][b].posY;
            item.addEventListener(e:Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function(e:MouseEvent){
                    Mouse.cursor = "hand";
                    e.target.startDrag(false);
                    Move = true
                    dusbin.visible = true;

            });

            item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function(e:MouseEvent){

                Mouse.cursor = "auto";
                e.target.stopDrag();
                externalPhpCall(e);
                dusbin.visible = false;
                if(trashClip){
                    removeChild(trashClip);
                    trashClip = null;
                }
            });
            item.mouseChildren = false;

            // if item is fence or flowers then move them behind the tree
            if(
                String(purchasedItems[a][b].item).indexOf('fence')!=-1
                ||
                String(purchasedItems[a][b].item).indexOf('flower')!=-1
            ){
                addChildAt(item,lastItemIndex);

                lastItemIndex++;
            } else {
                addChildAt(item,this.numChildren-2);
            }

            purchasedNameAr[getChildIndex(item)] = purchasedItems[a][b].item;

        }
        function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void{
         if(Move){
        // what ever here

        {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks friend, but e:Event do not have any property like e.stageX

Comment: obviously you may need to write this better, but it does work as i use this method with 3d applications

Answer (score 1):

Can't be sure, but I think it's probably that you're expecting a clip to continue to dispatch MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE events even once the mouse has left the clip - this won't happen, it's only whilst the local mouse pointer co-ordinates (ie yourClip.mouseX/mouseY) intersect the graphics of the clip itself that it will fire - even when dragging a clip, it can't be guaranteed that it will dispatch a MOVE event.

Let's suppose your clips are all on the root, which means you have access to 'stage' - you could do this:

replace:

```
item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMove);
```

with:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMove);
```

...but you should remember to remove that event when necessary (use stage again, in case mouse is not released over the clip):

```
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,endMove);


//Don't use anon function as won't have stage reference:

function endMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
        //The rest of your code, then:
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMove);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @MickMalone1983 but in my case I am moving clips while mouse is down and stop movement using mouse up. while moving i need the x and y values of my clip. but no luck :(

Comment: You can use the mouseMove function to get these, it will be sent a MouseEvent from which you can get e.target.x/y